# BeautifulSoup find two different strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently using Selenium and Beautiful soup to grab all the HTML data from a website. Currently all the data is stored in a variable in Python.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

What is the best way to look for the occurrence of two different words, either exactly "Open" or exactly "Closed" and print them to the console in the order that they are found.

I tried the following:

```
for node in soup.find_all(text=lambda x: x and "Open" in x):
print(node)
```

But how would I also get it to search for exactly "Closed"

**Updated code I have:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

status = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"pagebodydiv"})

with open("status.txt", "w") as file:
    for node in status.find_all(text=lambda t: t in ('Open', 'Closed')):
        file.write(node.encode("utf-8")+"\n")
```

Comment: Doesn't the element you want to scrap have a `class` or `id`?

Comment: the only unique tag it has is a font tag. Otherwise all the tags are the same and have no id's or classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here.

```
for node in soup.find_all(text=lambda t: t and any(x in t for x in ['Open', 'Closed'])):
    print(node)
```

This will be useful as a general solution. If you have more words to search for, you can simply add them in the list.

If you want to know what `any()` does, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

> **any(***iterable***):**
>
> > Return `True` if any element of the *iterable* is true. If the
> >     iterable is empty, return `False`. Equivalent to:
> >
> > ```
> > def any(iterable):
> >     for element in iterable:
> >         if element:
> >             return True
> >     return False
> > ```

---

**Edit:** Use the above solution if you want to search sentences that contain the specified words. But, if you want to match the exact text (as mentioned in the edited question), you can use what [@Jatimir mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779905/beautifulsoup-find-two-different-strings#comment86576185_49780254):

```
for node in soup.find_all(text=lambda t: t in ('Open', 'Closed')):
    print(node)
```

Comment: Why not `text=lambda t: t in ('Open', 'Closed')`? :D

Comment: Because, the text can contain words other than `Open` and `Closed`. For example `'this text contains Open' in ('Open', 'Closed')` won't work.

Comment: Ye, sure, I missed that. I thought OP just wants the elements containing exactly one of these. Sorry ^^

Comment: I'm actually having an issue with it. sometimes it will return sentences with the word open in it.

Comment: Don't you actually want that? Or do you only want the text that is exactly equal to `Close`? If so, can you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: I updated it. I need it only when its "exactly" = Open or Closed. If it find a sentence that contains Open or Closed it needs to disregard that.

Comment: Have a look at the edit. @Jatimir, looks like OP was after the same thing you thought he wanted.

Comment: So the first one works but it sometimes grabs data that contains open or close with additional text. The edit you provided outputs nothing.

Comment: Can you provide some example tags? Can't guess what you have

Comment: Updated original post with my code. The code follow before that just uses selenium web driver to navigate to the page that contains a table with the data I need. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to see the code, please post an example of what you are scraping. I am only guessing here without actually looking at the data. Maybe you have some whitespacing in the tags