# Find keyword from a list in a page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup, I'd like to detect porn keywords (that i get by concatening two lists of porn-keywords (one in french, the other in english) in a web page.

Here's my code (from [BeautifulSoup find two different strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779905/beautifulsoup-find-two-different-strings)):

```
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(my_proxies)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
lst_porn_keyword_eng = str(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/bad-words.txt").read()).split('\\n')
# the textfile starts with a LF, deleting it.
if lst_porn_keyword_eng[0] == "b\"":
   del lst_porn_keyword_eng[0]
lst_porn_keyword_fr = str(urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darwiin/french-badwords-list/master/list.txt").read()).split('\\n')

lst_porn_keyword = lst_porn_keyword_eng + lst_porn_keyword_fr
lst_porn_keyword_found = []

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.example.com") as page_to_check:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_check, "html5lib")
     for node in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: any(x in text for x in lst_porn_keyword)):
          lst_porn_keyword_found.append(str(node.text))

return lst_porn_keyword_found
```

This code runs correctly but porn keyword are found even if they shouldn't be.
For instance, the text of the second node found in "http://www.example.com" is
*This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.*
And none of these words are in lst_porn_keyword

Comment: This question could be reformulated only saying _specific keywords_ or just _keywords_. Technically, it doesn't matter which keywords they are.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. I guess i was too much inside my issue to formulate it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `soup.find_all()` doesn't return the html but the css instead:

```
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
```

The words "color", "gin", and the character " appear in `lst_porn_keyword` and on the css, which triggered your detection.

Partial words like "gin" in "margin" are also problematic using `soup.findall()`, consider using regular expressions with word delimiters like the example below:

```
import regex as re

for word in lst_porn_keyword:
    result = re.findall(fr"\W{word}\W", node)
    if len(result) > 0:
        print(f"detected in text: {word}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your lambda function with

```py
def testfn(text):
    elms = list([x for x in lst_porn_keyword if x in text])
    if len(elms) > 0:
        print(f"found words {elms} in {text}")
    return len(elms)>0
```

calling `soup.find_all(text=testfn)` will result in the following output:

```
found words ['color', 'gin', '"'] in `
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    `
found words ['cum', 'ho'] in `This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.`
```

I think your problem is that the `in` keyword also works for partial words. E.g.:

```
"cum" in "document"
> True
```

Comment: I agree for partial words, but for "gin" in "margin" as part of the css, not the html